# Finding Asymptotic bounds given a recurrent relation.

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

[image]

I am unsure of 2 parts here. I don't understand how expanding became the result above, and how geometric progression formula was applied to arrive to the resulting running time. Can anyone explain how I can solve these type of problems?

Comment: Is there a boundary condition, like $T(1)=1$ for example?

Comment: Knowledge of that isn't , necessary according to the Professor.